# Mechanism behind positive relationship between strain/loading rate and tensile strength

Tags: material-science, stress-strain

I am currently doing some study on the effect strain/loading rate on the breaking stress of a material during tensile testing. My experiments do show a positive relationship between the two, where breaking stress increases as loading rate increases.

However, I am unable to find a clear explanation of the mechanism for this phenomenon. Why does it work?

I read somewhere that says as strain/loading rate increases, the rate of dislocation formation will become greater and greater than dislocation elimination as it moves towards the grain boundaries, causing more pile-up of dislocations which increases tensile strength. Is this correct? I am unable to find any source that directly supports the explanation.

Thank you!